# SQL query to find out the name and salary of the employee who received highest salary for each month

Tags: mysql, sql

**SQL**  Here you can see I write below code that gives output of id and salary but I want name and salary

```
CREATE TABLE salary_data (
      id INTEGER NOT NULL,
      month INTEGER NOT NULL,
      salary INTEGER NOT NULL
    );
    -- another TABLE
    CREATE TABLE emp_data (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        name TEXT NOT NULL);
    -- insert some values
    INSERT INTO salary_data VALUES (1, 3,50000);
    INSERT INTO salary_data VALUES (2,4,45000);
    INSERT INTO salary_data VALUES (3,3,36000);
    INSERT INTO salary_data VALUES (4,5,72000);
    INSERT INTO salary_data VALUES (1,6,49000);
    INSERT INTO salary_data VALUES (4,4,51000);
    INSERT INTO salary_data VALUES (2,5,64000);
    INSERT INTO emp_data VALUES (1, "RAMESH");
    INSERT INTO emp_data VALUES (2, "SURESH");
    INSERT INTO emp_data VALUES (3, "NIKHIL");
    INSERT INTO emp_data VALUES (4, "RAJEEV");
    -- fetch some values
    SELECT id,max(salary) FROM salary_data GROUP BY month;
```

I think I am missing some in the last line

I want this type of output

name     salary,

ramesh  50000

like that

Comment: You did the first step and miss the second. You have found the highest salary per month. Now find the employees earning that much. Unfortunately, though, your database does not contain the information which employee earned what. Your salary_data table is lacking an employee ID in order to relate a salary to an employee. Or, wait, is the salary data ID supposed to be the employee ID?

Comment: Your query is invalid. You group by month, so you cannot select the ID, because there are multiple IDs per month. You are in MySQL's notorious cheat mode that allows such invalid queries. Make sure to get out of that mode by applying `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did the first step and miss the second. You have found the highest salary per month. Now find the employees earning that much.

Here is one way to do that:

```
select *
from salary_data s
join emp_data e on e.id = s.id -- s.id is a misnomer for s.emp_id
where (s.month, s.salary) in
(
  select month, max(salary)
  from salary_data
  group by month
);
```

Here is another (only possible since MySQL 8):

```
select *
from
(
  select
    id as emp_id, month, salary, 
    max(salary) over (partition by month) as max_salary_for_the_month
  from salary_data
) s
join emp_data e on e.id = s.emp_id
where s.salary = s.max_salary_for_the_month
order by s.month;
```